# Invalid POLYGON bigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, geospatial

I have a column with POLYGON strings, and before processing the geo data I need to convert them with ST_GEOGFROMTEXT.
However, I probably have some rows with invalid polygons and I get the following error

```
Error: ST_GeogFromText failed: Invalid polygon loop: Edge 0 has duplicate vertex with edge 4025
```

This is my query

```
SELECT st_geogfromtext(string_field_1)
FROM t
```

Is there a way to deal with incorrect polygons, or at least to identify which row returns the problem?

Answer (score 9):

Use prefix `SAFE`:

```
SELECT SAFE.st_geogfromtext(x), x
FROM (SELECT "bad" x)

null     bad
```

Comment: This deals with incorrect polygons, but doesn't identify which row returns the problem.

Comment: Please post a new question if you'd like a specific answer for your problem. This questions asks "Is there a way to deal with incorrect polygons", and we've delivered a solution for them.

Answer (score 2):

There is now a way to fix this problem in most cases, by using `make_valid` parameter:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/geography_functions#st_geogfromtext_signature2

Here is a query that find the invalid polygons, and attempt to fix it:

```
SELECT 
  st_geogfromtext(string_field_1, make_valid => TRUE) as geog,
  SAFE.st_geogfromtext(string_field_1) IS NULL as geog_needed_fix
FROM t
```